# Is it safe to use onInitializeTask function to track Android App Upgrade?

Tags: android, google-play-services, upgrade, gcmtaskservice

According to documentation, onInitializeTasks(https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService.html#onInitializeTasks()) is called whenever client side app/play services are updated. 
Can I safely use this callback to capture events when my app gets updated by play store?
Is there any known exception to the behavior?

Comment: what you mean by all app upgrade events.

Comment: By all app upgrade events, I meant that whenever my app gets updated by play store
Question edited to remove ambiguity.

Comment: You may check this [documentation](https://github.com/filipproch/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example/blob/master/README.md) for more information regarding `onInitializeTasks`. Usually, this method is called each time your package is removed or updated (taken from docs). Unfortunately, there is again no way to simple say: "I want to reschedule all my previous tasks". At the moment this method is called, they are all already canceled. You have to figure out somehow (maybe store it in configuration or whatever) which task you want to reschedule and reschedule them here.

Comment: Right. I understand that. But, can I use the same to do something every time my app is updated on the client? Other than rescheduling the tasks?